Duckdb sql and postgres results differ when using unnest
I have a table in postgres and basically i'm trying to duplicate rows based on the delimiter @ in the description column. Here is my table:



txn_id
description




3332654
CAD@10.00@0.9397@$10.64@THB@150.00@23.8235@$6.30@KRW@36,000.00@860.3722@$41.84@FJD@20.00@1.5711@$12.73@EUR@5.00@0.6013@$8.32@SGP@15.00@10.6013@$18.32


3332655
CAD@11.00@0.8197@$11.64@THB@110.00@21.8135@$61.30@KRW@36,001.00@861.3722@$411.84@FJD@21.00@11.5711@$11.73



Using the below postgresql code, the rows are duplicated based on a set of four values:
select txn_id 
  ,max(case when nr%4=1 then elem end) cncy_cd
  ,max(case when nr%4=2 then elem end) txn_cncy_amt
  ,max(case when nr%4=3 then elem end) txn_exch_rate
  ,max(case when nr%4=0 then elem end) txn_nzd_amt
from test t
left join lateral (select elem,row_number()over() nr 
  from  unnest(string_to_array(t.description, '@')) AS a(elem)) ON true  
group by txn_id,(nr-1)/4 ;

and the output will be:



txn_id
cncy_cd
txn_cncy_amt
txn_exch_rate
txn_nzd_amt




3332654
SGP
15.00
10.6013
$18.32


3332654
EUR
5.00
0.6013
$ 8.32


3332654
KRW
36,000.00
860.3722
$41.84


3332655
THB
36,001.00
861.3722
$411.84


3332654
FJD
150.00
23.8235
$6.30


3332654
CAD
20.00
1.5711
$12.73


3332654
FJD
10.00
0.9397
$10.64


3332655
CAD
21.00
11.5711
$11.73


3332655
THB
11.00
0.8197
$11.64


3332655
SGP
110.00
21.8135
$61.30



Below is the demo of the postgres code: https://dbfiddle.uk/BGOeoIlM
I'm trying to achieve the same result using duckdb and convert it to a polars dataframe and below is my code:
 a = duckdb.sql("create table test (txn_id int, description varchar(200));insert into test values (3332654,'CAD@10.00@0.9397@$10.64@THB@150.00@23.8235@$6.30@KRW@36,000.00@860.3722@$41.84@FJD@20.00@1.5711@$12.73@EUR@5.00@0.6013@$8.32@SGP@15.00@10.6013@$18.32'),(3332655,'CAD@11.00@0.8197@$11.64@THB@110.00@21.8135@$61.30@KRW@36,001.00@861.3722@$411.84@FJD@21.00@11.5711@$11.73');select txn_id ,max(case when nr%4=1 then elem end) cncy_cd ,max(case when nr%4=2 then elem end) txn_cncy_amt, max(case when nr%4=3 then elem end) txn_exch_rate ,max(case when nr%4=0 then elem end) txn_nzd_amt from test t left join lateral (select elem,row_number()over() nr from  unnest(string_to_array(t.description, '@')) AS a(elem)) ON true  group by txn_id,((nr-1)//4);")

Below is the output from duckdb and it does not match with the postgres output.



txn_id
cncy_cd
txn_cncy_amt
txn_exch_rate
txn_nzd_amt




3332654
FJD
$18.32
10.6013
15.00


3332655
THB
110.00
21.8135
$61.30


3332654
SGP
$8.32
0.6013
5.00


3332655
CAD
11.00
0.8197
$11.64


3332654
KRW
$6.30
23.8235
150.00


3332655
KRW
36,001.00
861.3722
$411.84


3332655
FJD
21.00
11.5711
$11.73


3332654
THB
$10.64
0.9397
10.00


3332654
EUR
$12.73
1.5711
20.00


3332654
CAD
$41.84
860.3722
36,000.00



Not sure what i'm missing here as i tried spending lot of time on this and could not figure out why it would behave differently. Great if someone could please help me with this?

Well, when using SQL you need to remember that in general SQL recordset is unordered collection of rows. Essentially, it means that there's no guaranteed order of rows when you select them without order by clause. This is one of the key differences with modern 'DataFrame' row collections and 'chained expressions' queries.
In your case it means that running row_number() over unnested array can be quite random - after array is unnested, you don't have order of array elements anymore. Basically, it's great that Postgres version works stable, but it's not a surprise that DuckDB doesn't work.
To get your code more production-ready, I'd suggest to use with ordinality clause in Postgres, which would number the rows of the function result set:
select
    txn_id,
    max(case when nr%4=1 then elem end) as cncy_cd,
    max(case when nr%4=2 then elem end) as txn_cncy_amt,
    max(case when nr%4=3 then elem end) as txn_exch_rate,
    max(case when nr%4=0 then elem end) as txn_nzd_amt
from test as t
    left join lateral unnest(string_to_array(t.description, '@')) with ordinality as a(elem, nr) on true  
group by
    txn_id,
    (nr-1)/4 ;

db<>fiddle
And in DuckDB you can use generate_subscripts function, which would generates indexes along Nth (in your case - first and only) dimension of the array:
duckdb.sql("""
    drop table if exists test;

    create table test (txn_id int, description varchar(200));
    
    insert into test
    values
        (3332654,'CAD@10.00@0.9397@$10.64@THB@150.00@23.8235@$6.30@KRW@36,000.00@860.3722@$41.84@FJD@20.00@1.5711@$12.73@EUR@5.00@0.6013@$8.32@SGP@15.00@10.6013@$18.32'),
        (3332655,'CAD@11.00@0.8197@$11.64@THB@110.00@21.8135@$61.30@KRW@36,001.00@861.3722@$411.84@FJD@21.00@11.5711@$11.73');
        
    select
        txn_id,
        max(case when nr%4=1 then elem end) cncy_cd,
        max(case when nr%4=2 then elem end) txn_cncy_amt,
        max(case when nr%4=3 then elem end) txn_exch_rate,
        max(case when nr%4=0 then elem end) txn_nzd_amt
    from test t
        left join lateral (select string_to_array(t.description, '@')) as a(data) on true
        left join lateral (select unnest(a.data), generate_subscripts(a.data, 1)) as b(elem, nr) on true
    group by
        txn_id,
        (nr-1)//4;
""")

┌─────────┬─────────┬──────────────┬───────────────┬─────────────┐
│ txn_id  │ cncy_cd │ txn_cncy_amt │ txn_exch_rate │ txn_nzd_amt │
│  int32  │ varchar │   varchar    │    varchar    │   varchar   │
├─────────┼─────────┼──────────────┼───────────────┼─────────────┤
│ 3332655 │ CAD     │ 11.00        │ 0.8197        │ $11.64      │
│ 3332654 │ THB     │ 150.00       │ 23.8235       │ $6.30       │
│ 3332655 │ FJD     │ 21.00        │ 11.5711       │ $11.73      │
│ 3332654 │ FJD     │ 20.00        │ 1.5711        │ $12.73      │
│ 3332655 │ KRW     │ 36,001.00    │ 861.3722      │ $411.84     │
│ 3332654 │ EUR     │ 5.00         │ 0.6013        │ $8.32       │
│ 3332654 │ SGP     │ 15.00        │ 10.6013       │ $18.32      │
│ 3332655 │ THB     │ 110.00       │ 21.8135       │ $61.30      │
│ 3332654 │ CAD     │ 10.00        │ 0.9397        │ $10.64      │
│ 3332654 │ KRW     │ 36,000.00    │ 860.3722      │ $41.84      │
├─────────┴─────────┴──────────────┴───────────────┴─────────────┤
│ 10 rows                                              5 columns │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘


It might be worth looking at list_slice(), a DuckDB function (see here).
The DuckDB documentation for unnest() says "when multiple lists are unnested in the same SELECT clause, the lists are unnested side-by-side."
I assume this means that the orders are kept the same and this appears to be the case, but not clear if this is guaranteed.
I used dplyr (R package) to generate the following SQL:
SELECT
  txn_id,
  unnest(list_slice(description, 1, length, 4)) AS cncy_cd,
  unnest(list_slice(description, 2, length, 4)) AS txn_cncy_amt,
  unnest(list_slice(description, 3, length, 4)) AS txn_exch_rate,
  unnest(list_slice(description, 4, length, 4)) AS txn_nzd_amt
FROM (
  SELECT q01.*, len(description) AS length
  FROM (
    SELECT txn_id, string_to_array(description, '@') AS description
    FROM df
  ) q01
) q01

R code:
library(tidyverse)
library(DBI)

db <- dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb())

df <- tribble(
  ~txn_id, ~description,
  3332654, "CAD@10.00@0.9397@$10.64@THB@150.00@23.8235@$6.30@KRW@36,000.00@860.3722@$41.84@FJD@20.00@1.5711@$12.73@EUR@5.00@0.6013@$8.32@SGP@15.00@10.6013@$18.32",
  3332655, "CAD@11.00@0.8197@$11.64@THB@110.00@21.8135@$61.30@KRW@36,001.00@861.3722@$411.84@FJD@21.00@11.5711@$11.73"
) |> copy_to(db, df = _, name = "df", overwrite = TRUE)

res <-
  df |>
  mutate(description = string_to_array(description, '@'),
         length = len(description)) |>
  mutate(cncy_cd = unnest(list_slice(description, 1L, length, 4L)),
         txn_cncy_amt = unnest(list_slice(description, 2L, length, 4L)),
         txn_exch_rate = unnest(list_slice(description, 3L, length, 4L)),
         txn_nzd_amt = unnest(list_slice(description, 4L, length, 4L))) |>
  select(-description, -length) |>
  collapse()

res |> show_query()
#> <SQL>
#> SELECT
#>   txn_id,
#>   unnest(list_slice(description, 1, length, 4)) AS cncy_cd,
#>   unnest(list_slice(description, 2, length, 4)) AS txn_cncy_amt,
#>   unnest(list_slice(description, 3, length, 4)) AS txn_exch_rate,
#>   unnest(list_slice(description, 4, length, 4)) AS txn_nzd_amt
#> FROM (
#>   SELECT q01.*, len(description) AS length
#>   FROM (
#>     SELECT txn_id, string_to_array(description, '@') AS description
#>     FROM df
#>   ) q01
#> ) q01


res |> collect() |> knitr::kable("pipe")




txn_id
cncy_cd
txn_cncy_amt
txn_exch_rate
txn_nzd_amt




3332654
CAD
10.00
0.9397
$10.64


3332654
THB
150.00
23.8235
$6.30


3332654
KRW
36,000.00
860.3722
$41.84


3332654
FJD
20.00
1.5711
$12.73


3332654
EUR
5.00
0.6013
$8.32


3332654
SGP
15.00
10.6013
$18.32


3332655
CAD
11.00
0.8197
$11.64


3332655
THB
110.00
21.8135
$61.30


3332655
KRW
36,001.00
861.3722
$411.84


3332655
FJD
21.00
11.5711
$11.73



Created on 2024-06-29 with reprex v2.1.0
